# Alternate for Read-Only in salesforce apex for 'collection size exceeds maximum size of 1000'

Tags: apex, visualforce

I got a scenario where I need to retrieve more than 1000 records using SOQL. If I set 'readOnly' option to 'true' my pages works fine. But, my present page is included in another page using  tag which is not giving me the flexibility to use readonly to the page and its resulting in 'Collection Size Exceeded' error message.

It would be a great help for me if anyone suggest on how to Overcome 'Collection Size exceeded' error message

Comment: Did you try nested repeats of outer and inner collections?

Comment: @Bartley Initially when i retrieve more than 1000 records to a list, there is no error. this error is rising when I'm passing each record(of 1000+ records) to a method and adding  the result of the method to another list. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to solve this issues

1)Use pagination to paginate data.Use offset and don't show all records instead after user clicks on Next buttons fetch data accordingly.

2)Get rid of view state.Make page stateless .This will require you to use some jQuery plugin for tabulating and paging your data.Couple I have used are Datatables and JqGrid.

Comment: Two answers doesn't fit my requirement because i need to display them in Excel page.

Comment: For Excel use HandsOn table library

Comment: HandsOn table lib is unable to handle/restrict the error